# How to calculate tolerance for TopologyPreservingSimplifier in JTS?

Tags: simplify, geometry-conversion, jts-topology-suite

I am trying to simplify some areal geometries (POLYGON\MULTIPOLYGON) using JTS's

```
TopologyPreservingSimplifier.simplify(Geometry geom, double distanceTolerance)
```

From the [JavaDoc](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/simplify/TopologyPreservingSimplifier.html):

```
 void   setDistanceTolerance(double distanceTolerance) 
          Sets the distance tolerance for the simplification.
```

I cannot understand what should be specified for the distanceTolerance paramter, I would like to have a tolerance of 0.1 Km (or miles).

Do I need to convert the input to decimal degrees ? If so, what conversion can that be used accurately for most of the globe ?

Comment: Meaning of tolerance is about "how far apart the original and the simplified borderline are allowed to be".

Comment: JTS has no concept of projection or units, so the distance is **always** in the units of your data